# sql query difference and best case from two options

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `emp` with the following columns:

```
id int (autoincrement), 
name varchar,
maxid int
```

I want to insert `id`, `name`, and `maxid` where `maxid` should be the value of autoincrement `id`.

Out of the two query options below, which one is best option and why?

option 1:

```
insert into emp (name,maxid) values ('abc',(select max(id)+1 from emp))
```

option 2:

```
string QRY = "insert into emp values('abc',0) select scope_identity()";
sqlcommand cmd= new sqlcommand(QRY, con);
datatable dt = new datatable();
con.open();
dt.load(cmd.executereader());  
con.close();
int scopeid=int.parse(dt.rows[0][0].tostring());

QRY="update emp set maxid='"+scopeid+"' where id ='"+scopeid+"'";
cmd= new sqlcommand(QRY, con);
cmd.executenonquery();
```

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something useless.
Maxid will just always* be equal to id

* unless you have bugs.

If you really need a maxid = id, just create a view or a computed column instead.

Comment: hope a knowledge geek can understand my problem, thanks for your review

Comment: can u provide an example ? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy way to do  [Demo is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26580/1)

> insert    dbo.emp
>   select     'abc', IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.emp')

Comment: Great idea, but since Identity will change before IDENT_CURRENT is called, I think +1 is not needed at the end

Comment: "Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for _any session and any scope_."  [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098(v=sql.100).aspx).  Hopefully in a single statement it is either the value you want or one that was assigned by a trigger fired by your statement.

Answer (score 2):

None of above are correct implementation of update.

But according to your scenario i would do two things.

First insert the names and use the auto increment to set the id and after that perform update no those records that do not have set yet the maxId.

Why do this in two stages ?

It is possible that we could have different result from MAX(id) and value of id set by incremental feature by database, so option 1 must be drop.

The query that could be used.

```
insert into emp (name) values ('abc')
update emp set maxid = id where maxid is null;
```

But from other hand and Serge observation, you should entirely drop this behavior if possible. Another alternative is to crate a trigger that kick after insert. Advantage of this is that above view or computed column is that you perform this operation only once.

Comment: can you elaborate by an example?? that can help more, thanks in adv.

Comment: Here you have a snippets with parameter usage http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0360__ADO.net-Database/InsertupdateanddeleteC.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'll rather use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO emp (name, maxid) 
SELECT 'abc', COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 
FROM   emp
```

Comment: it seems to be same as option 1, but which one is the best option from those as per concurrency and speed ?

Comment: for me, one statement is better than two `:D` I go for option 1.

Comment: not as per code but what is best by speed, and high concurrency and accuracy?

Comment: i still go for option 1. remember that creating a connection on the database causes too much resources.

Answer (score 1):

`Select max(id)+1` could be different from autoincrement id so that option is not valid.

As for the second option it's still unnecessary complication. You can just insert with maxid NULL and then update to id

```
insert into emp (name,maxid) values ('abc',NULL)

update emp set maxid = id where maxid is null
```

Comment: @merhardik Also you don't need to open two connections to execute two queries, you can send them at the same time.